# Twilio sends bad request

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm building a rather complex Twilio voice application. It consists of call recordings and call manipulation. Right now, I'm facing an issue, where twilio will shut downs the call with "an application error has occured". The call flow looks like this:

1. Outgoing call is made when correct POST requests come to the application
2. Twilio will play message for the callee and waits for his answer
3. After several seconds, the recording is stopped and downloaded
4. Recording is processed in backend
5. If so, message is played for the callee again
6. Twilio will wait for his answer again
7. After several seconds twilio ends the call with error message, because it sends POST request which cant be processed.

Other POST and GET requests are valid. The IP address to which the bad request is heading is not defined in the application.

Error ID is 11100.
Error in request body says "Blacklisted IP". But it should not create that request in first place!
Data in request parameters looks like standart status callback POST. But the callback is set to point to application.
Description: An attempt to retrieve content from http://ip_address/and/Accounts/some/Calls/additional/twiml/parameters returned the HTTP status code 502

There is no issue when I'm not manipulating with the call.

Thank you for any advice.